# VBA - Target as Range

Tags: excel, function, runtime-error, vba

Good morning. My problem is connected with run-time error '91' - object variable not set. I don't know what is the reason for that error. Code below:

```
Function Zakres(kol_zakr As Long, rng_zakr As Range) As Range
    Zakres = rng_zakr.Worksheet.Range(CStr(Module1.Kolumna_litera(CLng(kol_zakr)) & Module1.wier_pierwszy & ":" & Kolumna_litera(CLng(kol_zakr)) & Module1.wier_ostatni))
End Function
```

Comment: How are you calling the function? Perhaps you didn't pass a valid range object.

Comment: Zakres(y, Target) - where Target is the argument of a private sub and y is the column number of target cell

Comment: What private sub? I assume you do actually have a module called `Module1` in that workbook?

Comment: Yes, but I also have a private sub working on Worksheet_Change event.  And, of course, Module1 is not fictive :)

Comment: Just noticed, you're missing `Set`: `Set  Zakres = rng_zakr.Worksheet.Range(CStr(Module1.Kolumna_litera(CLng(kol_zakr)) & Module1.wier_pierwszy & ":" & Kolumna_litera(CLng(kol_zakr)) & Module1.wier_ostatni))`

Comment: You're right. Thank you very much.